# Overriding core user data files for Magepack

Tags: magento2, performance, jsbundling

We are working on getting Magepack installed on our dev environment.  One of the shims we had to fix was in the "customer-data.js".  It works when we edit the core file(vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js), but when we try and put it into the "app/code" file, the override doesn't seem to work.
This is what we are trying.
app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js

We've deployed, clear cache, everything, but that file does not override for some reason